# I want to compare two lists in different worksheets in Excel to locate any duplicates

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I know this is very simple but I still need help:

I have a list of properties that have finished a training. I need the names of the ones that have not done this training, but the system does not give me such a list. However, I have a list of all our properties. That means I have to compare two columns in different worksheets.

The properties are identified by `ID` Numbers. What would make my life easier is that if there is a `formula` that can detect `duplicates` and highlight on the complete list of hotels so the ones that are not highlighted have not done the training.

Let me know if you have any recommendations for me!

Answer (score 8):

Without VBA...

If you can use a helper column, you can use the `MATCH` function to test if a value in one column exists in another column (or in another column on another worksheet). It will return an Error if there is no match

**To simply identify duplicates, use a helper column**

Assume data in Sheet1, Column A, and another list in Sheet2, Column A.  In your helper column, row 1, place the following formula:

`=If(IsError(Match(A1, 'Sheet2'!A:A,False)),"","Duplicate")`

Drag/copy this forumla down, and it should identify the duplicates.

**To highlight cells, use conditional formatting:**

With some tinkering, you can use this `MATCH` function in a Conditional Formatting rule which would highlight duplicate values. I would probably do this *instead* of using a helper column, although the helper column is a great way to "see" results before you make the conditional formatting rule.

Something like:

`=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1, 'Sheet2'!A:A,FALSE)))`

[image: Conditional formatting for Excel 2010]

For Excel 2007 and prior, you cannot use conditional formatting rules that reference other worksheets. In this case, use the helper column and set your formatting rule in column A like:

`=B1="Duplicate"`

This screenshot is from the 2010 UI, but the same rule should work in 2007/2003 Excel.

[image: Conditional formatting using helper column for rule]

Comment: Thanks for the help I have tried conditional formatting but it says that I cannot use reference to another sheet

Comment: references to other sheets in conditional formatting (and data validation) can only be done in Excel 2010 and later. For earlier versions, you need to have the data in the same sheet. For reasons like this, it's a good idea to state your Excel version when asking questions.

Comment: @user2384032 per teylyn's comment, you can't use that sort of conditional formatting on previous versions of Excel, but I revised my answer with a new conditional formatting rule based on the helper column/first formula that is working for you.  Check it out :)  And as always, if this has solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as "Accepted".  Cheers.

Comment: @pnuts really? Never thought of that nor seen it mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: I used excel 2003 only until last year @pnuts :)

Comment: @pnuts, I was not talking about named ranges, but references to a sheet range. Named ranges will always work in CF and DV situations, not matter what the Excel version.