# VBA to highlight duplicate rows in two Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I know very little about VBA code, but I can follow along the lines of logic in a given example. So I googled and found a code I edited to highlight duplicates in a worksheet. However, I have a workbook with three sheets. I would like to adapt this to compare sheet 1 and sheet 3, then highlight the duplicates in sheet 1.

```
Sub Highlight_Dups()

Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = 2

Dim row As Integer
row = startRow

Do While (Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

Dim innerRow As Integer
innerRow = row + 1

Dim StudentID As String
Dim DT As String
Dim Description As String

StudentID = Range("A" & row).Value
DT = Range("H" & row).Value
Description = Range("J" & row).Value

Do While (Range("A" & innerRow).Value <> "")


    If (Range("A" & innerRow).Value = StudentID And Range("H" & innerRow).Value = DT And Range("J" & innerRow).Value = Description) Then
        Range("X" & row).Value = Range("X" & row).Value & innerRow & ", "
        Range("X" & innerRow).Value = Range("X" & innerRow).Value & row & ", "
        Rows(row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

        Rows(innerRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If

innerRow = innerRow + 1
Loop

row = row + 1
Loop

MsgBox "done", vbOKOnly, "done"

End Sub
```

Any help on how to add ???= Sheets("Sheet1") and ??? = Sheets("Sheet3")
would help me a great deal. Thanks

Comment: You can store the values in variables and then compare variables using `IF` statement.

Comment: You can fully qualify ranges as well to indicate which sheets you are comparing e.g. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & innerRow).Value says the range in sheet1 in workbook holding the code. You could further adapt this to use a WITH statement.

Comment: you need one of two things .... two nested loops: one that iterates sheet1. second one that iterates sheet3 with comparison code inside the inner loop. .... the other way: one loop that iterates sheet1 with code that runs a find command   .... record a macro of running a find on sheet3 and then add the resulting code to your `do while` loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555816/i-want-to-compare-two-lists-in-different-worksheets-in-excel-to-locate-any-dupli

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should declare 2 sheet objects to make it easier to read and future code maintences easier:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

'use this approach if your sheet's name is dinamic but never changes it's order
'Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

'use this if name is static
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name of worksheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name of worksheet2")
```

Then just put the Sheets objects in their specific locations like this (pay attention to the 'ws1's and 'ws2's):

```
Dim StudentID As String
Dim DT As String
Dim Description As String

Do While (ws1.Range("A" & Row).Value <> "")
    innerRow = Row + 1

    StudentID = ws1.Range("A" & Row).Value
    DT = ws1.Range("H" & Row).Value
    Description = ws1.Range("J" & Row).Value

    Do While (ws2.Range("A" & innerRow).Value <> "")

        If (ws2.Range("A" & innerRow).Value = StudentID And ws2.Range("H" & innerRow).Value = DT And ws2.Range("J" & innerRow).Value = Description) Then
            'not sure what you are trying to do with this 3 lines, change it for your own needs
            ws1.Range("X" & Row).Value = ws2.Range("X" & Row).Value & innerRow & ", "
            ws1.Range("X" & innerRow).Value = ws2.Range("X" & innerRow).Value & Row & ", "
            ws1.Rows(Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

            ws1.Rows(innerRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If

        innerRow = innerRow + 1
    Loop

    Row = Row + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

ps: i couldn't test it since you didn't provide the base of yours. But since you said you can read code and understand it's logic, I think you'll be fine :)

Comment: Thank you!  I tried and get Run-time  error91 object variable or with block variable not set

Answer (score 0):

You  might want to consider discarding the laborious task of looping through every cell while comparing it to every other and use a pair of conditional formatting rules.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cfrS1S3dupes()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "J"))
            'get rid of pre-existing cfrs
            .FormatConditions.Delete

            'if duplicate in sheet1 found below row, then fill red
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=countifs($a$2:$a2, $a2, $h$2:$h2, $h2, $j$2:$j2, $j2)>1")
                .Interior.Color = 255 'this is the color red
            End With

            'if duplicate anywhere in sheet3, then fill green
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=countifs(sheet3!$a:$a, $a2, sheet3!$h:$h, $h2, sheet3!$j:$j, $j2)")
                .Interior.Color = 5287936 'this is the color green
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You!, but it is not highlighting all the dups. As a test I copied 12 rows from worksheet 3 to 1 and it highlighted 9 of them?

Comment: Rerun the routine. You have changed the CFR range but not the Applies To:.